# Java Logical Array Trouble

Tags: java, arrays, integer

I am trying to make an `Array` so that it contains 10 different integers 0-9. 
I have this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < perm.length; i++) 
 { 
    int num = (int) (Math.random() * 9); 
    boolean check = true;

    if (Arrays.asList(perm).contains(num) == true) 

      check = false; 
        else 
          {
           check = true; 
           perm[i] = num; 
          } 

 while (check == false) 
 { 
   num = (int) (Math.random() * 9); 

    } 
}
```

It seems that it should work and make an array with different integers, but it does not.

Comment: "but it does not"; can you be more specific?

Comment: what exactly does perm.length equal? Also, if check == true your while loop is an infinite loop.

Comment: perm.length is 10. When I say "it does not" I mean the code I wrote is not functioning how I intended and some numbers are still being repeated in the array.

Comment: Please don't type the code, copy&paste it. What is the point of people looking at the wrong code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid creating a List you can just shuffle yourself :

```
    Random random = new Random();
    int[] perm = new int[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        perm[i] = i;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        int j = random.nextInt(10 - i);
        int tmp = perm[i];
        perm[i] = perm[i + j];
        perm[i + j] = tmp;
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(perm));
```

Comment: I have to use the Math.random() generator to fill the array.

Comment: @user1729448, so just use it. Don't be lazy to only copy-paste.

Comment: The call to Random can easily be substituted with (int) (Math.random() * (10 - i))  (Random class is just easier)

Answer (score 1):

How about this instead (if you want a more concise approach):

```
List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    l.add(i);  // add 0-9
Collections.shuffle(l)

Integer[] ints = l.toArray(new Integer[10]);
```

All we're doing here is creating a list, filling it with the integers 0-9, shuffling it, and writing the contents to an array.

---

If you want a more 'manual' approach, I'd suggest something like this:

```
List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   l.add(i);  // add 0-9

int[] ints = new int[10];
for (int i = 0 ; i < 10; i++)
    ints[i] = l.remove((int)(Math.random() * l.size()));

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ints));
```

```
[7, 2, 3, 4, 9, 6, 0, 1, 8, 5]
```

I'm assuming that you're allowed to use lists, since the code you posted includes a call to `Arrays.asList`.

Comment: I know that this would be easier, but we can not use what we haven't learned yet. Therefore I have to use the `Math.random()` generator to fill the array.

Comment: We are not actually allowed to use `Lists`. I just wanted to see if I could get it working first then adjust it. Is there anyway to do it like how you did without `Lists`?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to generate a permutation of the numbers from 0 to 8 (9?). The easiest way to do this is to fill an array list with the numbers in sequence, and then use [`Collections.shuffle()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29).